# CSS: List with images, texts and image scaling animation - layout problem

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to use a two-column list. Every item should compose of image to the left and next to it, on the right, headline and text. The images have a CSS scale transformation set on onMouseEnter (in ReactJS code).

The problem is that when I use float:left for the images (to align them left to the texts) layout breaks. If I try to set overflow:auto to the `<li>` element, the images zoom-in animation doesn't work properly (the image gets sliced by the `<li>` box boundaries).

What is the best way to set the layout so that the `<li>` elements would not get mixed and the `<img>` elements in the list items would display properly, that is on the left of the texts and not sliced when scaled?

Image of the list:

[image]

List with zoomed-in image, image clipped with box boundaries:

[image]

```css
li {
  overflow: auto;
}


/* sets transition to transform and defines the length */

li img {
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  width: 150px;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  float: left;
}


/* describes the transformation itself */

li img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.8);
}

li:hover {
  background: papayawhip;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.forexsrovnavac.cz/assets/img/turecka-lira-euro-dolar-kurzy.png" />
    <div className="list-text">
      <h3>Headline</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

        </>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.forexsrovnavac.cz/assets/img/turecka-lira-euro-dolar-kurzy.png" />
    <div className="list-text">
      <h3>Headline</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

        </>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: `overflow` isn’t the only way to encapsulate floating children - https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#article-header-id-4 Going completely without floating and using flexbox instead would of course also be a relatively easy solution here.

Comment: @Paulie_D I hoped I had included all the necessary code, but based on your comment I added a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that clearing the `<li>` while setting the image to `float: left` was all that was needed. Thanks Paulie_D for his reference (this article on [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#article-header-id-4)).

```css
li {
  clear: both;
}


/* sets transition to transform and defines the length */

li img {
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  width: 150px;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  float: left;
}


/* describes the transformation itself */

li img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.8);
}

li:hover {
  background: papayawhip;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.forexsrovnavac.cz/assets/img/turecka-lira-euro-dolar-kurzy.png" />
    <div className="list-text">
      <h3>Headline</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

        </>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.forexsrovnavac.cz/assets/img/turecka-lira-euro-dolar-kurzy.png" />
    <div className="list-text">
      <h3>Headline</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

        </>
    </div>
  </li>
```